# Why does this 6V solenoid activate on 4 AA batteries but not on a MT3608 step up booster?

Tags: power, solenoid, step-up

I have a JF-0530B 6V solenoid that is rated at 300mA, and if I hook it up to 4 AA batteries it indeed activates on the roughly 6V the batteries supply. However, I also have an MT3608 step up converter hooked up to a 5V line on an ATX power supply. I have set the potentiometer on the converter so that it outputs 6V - I measured this using a multimeter just to make sure.

If I hook the solenoid up to the power converter, nothing happens, despite it outputting 6V, like the batteries. The power converter is rated to put out 2A max, with a recommended 1A output, which is more than enough for the 300mA solenoid. Yet, nothing happens.

Why can the solenoid activate on the 6V supplied by 4 AA batteries, yet not on the 6V supplied by the power converter?

Edit: if I measure the solenoid's resistance, I measure about 3.8 ohms, which is surprising because at 6V that would mean about 1.5A, not the 300mA it is rated at. If I measure the current of the circuit when hooked up to the batteries, I measure 1.1A, which is lower than calculated but still a lot. When hooked up to the converter, the current is 0.95A. I measured the converter's output under load, and it's 3.35V. So that would at least explain why the solenoid isn't activating. However, those currents all seem to be within range of the converter's output..

[This is the converter in question](https://www.tinytronics.nl/shop/nl/spanning-converters/step-up/dc-dc-verstelbare-step-up-boost-converter-mt3608-2a), basically it's one of those ubiquitous cheap MT3608-based step up converter circuits out there.

Comment: (1) Measure the DC resistance of the solenoid. (2) Calculate the expected current at 6 V. (3) Measure the actual current at 6 V. (4) Measure the current from your converter. (5) Double-check the converter voltage under load. (6) Provide a link / schematic for the converter. Without this information we're all guessing.

Comment: Measure the voltage at the solenoid coil when it's connected to the booster.  Sometimes switching supplies can get discombobulated by unexpected loads.

Comment: @Transistor, I added the requested information to the original post.

Comment: @TimWescott I think you're on to something... any suggestions on how I might remedy this?

Comment: @Bas. I saw your update. I think you've learned a few things already. I was thinking of converter instability with an inductive load too but have never had the problem in practice. I suspect that the solution will be getting the right capacitance or maybe a 0.5 ohm series resistor to damp down any oscillations enough.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of hobby electronics, where you can't ever quite trust your vendors.  How to remedy this depends on what makes you happy -- I'd find a more reliable source of parts.  If possible I'd buy from distributors that cater to small electronics firms (i.e., DigiKey, Newark, and Mouser in the US).

Comment: The alternative is to go ahead and buy cheap stuff from the surplus or China market, and test everything as it comes in the door.  For instance, I'm pretty sure those power supply modules that are so ubiquitous are just copied from vendor's data sheets, without any characterization or testing.

Comment: 0

Measure the voltage on your 4 AA batteries, it could be more than 6V if they are new

connect the voltmeter and the solenoid at the same time -

Comment: @Transistor any chance you could expand on that, or would it be wiser to just buy some more reliable electronics and go from there?

Comment: @TimWescott thanks, lesson learned I suppose.

Comment: @Transistor was referring to the fact that power supply circuits can go unstable when presented with unexpected loads.  Most power supplies are designed to work into something that looks like a resistor in parallel with a capacitor -- working into an inductor may make the thing oscillate, or at least overshoot and (if it is so equipped) activate some sort of overcurrent or overvoltage limit.

Comment: I think the boost converter is unstable while supplying current to load, it may be resetting itself while it is trying to supply the current, that's why maybe the current less than 1.1A.

Comment: @Bas Tim's comments are well-placed. I purchased some cheap (similar, but not the same) boards at about $1 each. (Two dozen, I think.) The first one I quickly destroyed (and threw away.) But I pretty much knew the problem then. It cannot be powered up without a load present. (It destroys itself without one.) Adding a simple resistor was all that was needed. I've had zero problem with the rest of them. Sometimes, what you get does work okay -- if and only if you add something to them. They really do skimp on the design side and will use idealized behavioral schematics without thinking more.

Comment: It brings up an issue of how different power supplies react to purely inductive loads. The batteries have an "I don't care" response, while switch-mode supplies that are missing a resistive pre-load may not be able to run.

Comment: _"When hooked up to the converter, the current is 0.95A. I measured the converter's output under load, and it's 3.35V."_- What was the measured **input** voltage?

Comment: @BruceAbbott it's 5V from an ATX power supply.

Comment: @jonk Interesting stuff... So you would just put the resistor in parallel with the solenoid? Worth a try. What value resistor would that be? Something that just draws a couple milliamps? Like, say, a 1K ohm resistor? Or am I underthinking this?

Comment: Well, adding a 1K resistor didn't do much. Without the solenoid, the voltage measured across the resistor is a nice 6V.. as soon as the solenoid gets added in parallel with the resistor voltage drops back to 3.35V. I guess this converter goes in the junk bin for now.

Comment: The MT3608 only boosts voltage, it cannot buck it. The 'dropout' voltage should be less than 0.6V at 1.3A. So if your output voltage is 3.35V the input voltage cannot be above 4V - unless the converter is faulty. Please _measure_ the voltage at the converter input (with the solenoid connected), and tell us what you get.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Interesting. I hooked it up to the 5V PSU and set it to output 6V without load. I measured both ends and indeed 5V is coming in, and 6V is coming out. However, if I attach the solenoid now, it suddenly activates, where it did not do so before. Measuring the input voltage with the solenoid connected, the values fluctuate wildly between 0V and 3.35V - it sometimes stays at the latter for a second or two. Measuring the output voltage (with the solenoid connected and active) gives 4.98V. 

What on earth is going on?

Comment: _"Measuring the input voltage with the solenoid connected, the values fluctuate wildly between 0V and 3.35V"_ - The power supply voltage is not stable. Perhaps you need to put a dummy load on the ATX PSU to make it stable, or perhaps you are using the 'standby' 5V output which cannot deliver the required current. https://powersupply33.com/atx-power-supply-pinout.html